# The right API for a windows app?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I want to include Google place search and place details in my C# windows app.

What API should I use?  The simplest way seems to be to use the web API but that requires an API key and I would rather not have to instruct the user on how to create an API key as it would create unnecessary support.

I want the place data independent of the map so the JSON object is perfect.  Is there a way to do this for client side apps or do I need to get user to create their own API key?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use Web API, most likely [Google Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/)

For any Google API, you will need to have an API key. User don't have to create it. It just needs to be created by you and added to your code in order to identify of your application